# How do I create an executable file in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've been learning clojure on the REPL environment with Clojure Box.

How can I make an executable file (.jar)?

I'm wondering if something like this is possible:

1. write clojure code on notepad and name it project.clj
2. compile project.clj
3. get executable file

Step #2 doesn't have to be done in command line. IDE is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) to create an [uberjar](http://clojuredocs.org/leiningen/leiningen.uberjar/uberjar).

Comment: Are there any alternatives to Leiningen?

Comment: @Da9 maven with clojure plugin, [see](http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureMaven.html).

Answer (score 10):

As Erhan Bagdemir answered, you should use Leiningen. Here's how I do it on Windows:

### Install Leiningen on Windows

You're going to download the Leiningen script and put it somewhere on your `PATH`. If you have a folder already on your path that you use for executable scripts, if not, do the following:

1. Download the [Leiningen package from Github](https://github.com/downloads/technomancy/leiningen/leiningen-1.5.2-win.zip).
2. Unzip it in your home folder (e.g. `/Users/vikbehal`)
3. Add the folder that was created by unzipping to your `PATH`. To do this, open the Control Panel, and go to the System area where you can edit your Environment Variables. Edit either the system or your user's `PATH` value by adding `/Users/vikbehal/lein` (or whatever the folder is called) to your `PATH`, making sure to keep that entry separated from others by a semicolon (`;`).
4. Press `Ok` to save your changes.

You can verify that you've successfully installed Leiningen by opening up a command prompt and running `lein help`. You should see Leiningen installing some initial files. If you get an error, make sure you've properly added the folder where Leiningen lives to your `PATH`.

### Use Leiningen to Develop

Leiningen gives you a good default directory structure, handles dependency management, and ensures that Java's classpath is set properly when running a REPL or, in this case, jarring your application.

Here's a run-down of Leiningen standard commands:

```
# Start a blank project
lein new my-project

# Pull down dependencies defined in your project.clj file
lein deps

# Create a "library" jar of your project
lein jar

# Create an executable jar of your project
lein uberjar
```

It looks like that last command is what you want, right? First, you need to configure a few things, so that Leiningen can build your executable jar properly.

### Configuring for an Executable/Standalone Jar

You need to do three things to make `lein uberjar` work properly:

1. Write a `-main` function that will act as the "entry point" to the execution of your jar file. (Note the `-`, it denotes that this function is more like a "Java method" than a regular Clojure function.)
2. Make sure you add a `(:gen-class :main true)` declaration in the `ns` namespace declaration at the top of the file that contains your `-main` function.
3. Add a `:main my.main.namespace` entry in your `project.clj`

Now run `lein uberjar`. While developing, you can alternatively use `lein run` if you want to test how your application would behave as an executable jar, but don't want to explicitly re-jar every time you make a change.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\x0163093>lein
Leiningen is a build tool for Clojure.

Several tasks are available:
  Problem loading leiningen.classpath - home-dir does not exist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
class leiningen.classpath__init (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)

Comment: Good info.  I'll have to go back and try it again.  Last time I tried Leiningen it was a rather dismal failure.  :-)

Comment: Should be as simple as sticking the `lein` script on your PATH. The first time you use the `lein` command, it will auto-download everything it needs to run.

Answer (score 3):

with Leiningen:

http://www.bagdemir.com/2011/07/04/creating-new-projects-with-leiningen/

Comment: Can you suggest for Windows OS?

Comment: There is also a windows distro: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/downloads

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety I though I would mention the [maven clojure plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) for those who want to keep to their Java roots.